# To whom is it not a mitzvah to give tzedakah?

Tags: rambam, tzedakah-charity, mishneh-torah

I seem to recall a Rambam that says that if someone can work and chooses not to, there is no mitzvah to support such a person. But I can't find it. Am I mis-remembering?

EDIT: Is there something on the subject in the other rishonim and aharonim?

Comment: Could you be thinking of Rambam's condemnation (Hilkhot Talmud Torah 3:10) of people who refuse to work, become poor and then take charity money?

Comment: No-this passage had to do with whether one has to give to such a person.

Comment: There is a din with someone who sold himself to goym several times, not to buy him again

Comment: If you wish views from other Rishonim/Ahronim (your comment above) you should note so in the question above. You an [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/86617/edit) your question here. I will edit my answer to add some

Comment: @B111 Goyim? ........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you maybe remembering [the end of Hilkhot Tshuva](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Gifts_to_the_Poor.10.18?lang=bi) (10:18) in Rambam’s Mishne Torah where he writes:

> One should always strain oneself and endure hardship and not come to
>   depend on others rather than cast oneself onto the community. Thus the
>   sages commanded, "Make your Sabbaths into weekdays rather than come to
>   depend on others." Even if one is wise and revered and becomes poor,
>   he should engage in some kind of craft, even a menial one, rather than
>   come to depend on others. [...]  Great sages were splitters of wood, raisers of beams, drawers of water for gardens, ironworkers, and blacksmiths rather than ask [for their living] from the community or accept anything when they gave to them.

---

Or in the very last part (10:19) he writes:
‎

> Anyone who does not need [tzedakah] but deceives people and takes will
>   not reach death in old age without having come to depend upon others
>   [in reality].

---

You added in a comment above that you are also interested in views of other Rishonim and Ahronim. I would therefore point out some interesting sources from [here](http://5tjt.com/but-is-it-tzedakah-2/)

> Rabbi Shmuel di Medina of Salonika (1506-1580)  writes in his responsa
>   (Teshuvos Maharshdam YD #166) that there is no obligation to provide
>   charitable funds even to a poor person who has the capacity to work.
>
> This view can further be buttressed with the explanation of the Kli
>   Yakar on Chumash ([Shmot 23:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.23.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)): “You shall surely help with him”
>   discussing the Mitzvah of Prikah and Teinah – assisting one’s fellow
>   with a load.
>
> This (the words “with him”) teaches you that it is only when he is
>   with you in his work – and wishes to be established with you – then
>   you are obligated to support him.  However, if he sits and says,
>   “Since the matter is upon you – you must lift it alone..” – it does
>   not apply.
>
> He further writes:  “From here we have a response to a minority of the
>   poor among our nation who place themselves upon the community and do
>   not wish to work in any area of work even though they are able to do
>   so.. And they cry foul if they are not given enough to sustain them. 
>   For on this, Hashem did not command, rather it states, “You shall
>   surely help WITH HIM” and you shall surely establish it WITH HIM. For
>   the poor person will do all he can find by himself to do, and if even
>   then his hand cannot reach it, then each man of Israel is obligated to
>   help him and strengthen him and give him what he is lacking.. even up
>   to one hundred times.”
>
> In Sefer Maalos HaMidos at the end of Hilchos Tzedakah, the author
>   writes:  “Nonetheless, it is worthy to refrain from giving him
>   Tzedakah and embarrass him and shame him until he repents and tries
>   working again so that he not be shameful in the eyes of people.”

Comment: No-I remember it dealing with whether someone has an obligation to give to person who chooses to beg rather than work.

Comment: IIRC, there is something in Avot Derav Nattan that somewhat expands on the 2nd citing. B"N, I'll see if I can locate it.

Comment: the only real edit was to avoid another question on miyodeya of "haow come rav Shmuel di Medina lived till 174?" very well researched answer though